# htaccess remove subdirectory from url

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I have read multiple threads based on this subject but none of the rules have worked so i'm sure i m doing something wrong.

I have the following struncture in my /var/www

```
main domain folders that redirects to domain.com
folder1 that redirects to domain1.com
folder2 that redirects to domain2.com
```

Inside folder2 i have 3 more subdirectories

```
folder2/subdirectory1
folder2/subdirectory2
folder2/subdirectory3
```

These should redirect to:

```
www.domain2.com/subdirectory1
www.domain2.com/subdirectory2
www.domain2.com/subdirectory3
```

but instead of that it also shows the folder2 in the url so it's listing

```
www.domain2.com/folder2/subdirectory1
www.domain2.com/folder2/subdirectory2
www.domain2.com/folder2/subdirectory3
```

I have two .htaccess: one inside the root folder and one inside folder2

htaccess from root folder

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1.com
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder1/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ folder1/$1 [L] 

ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.com
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder2/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ folder2/$1 [L]
```

htaccess from folder2

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.com/subdirectory1
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subdirectory1/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ subdirectory1/$1 [L] 

ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.com/subdirectory2
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subdirectory2/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ subdirectory2/$1 [L] 

ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.com/subdirectory3
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subdirectory3/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ subdirectory3/$1 [L]
```

Hopefully i can finally fix this problem

Comment: Your rewrite rules in folder2 are not doing anything: `ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.com/subdirectory1` will never match anything. `%{HTTP_HOST}` only contains the domain portion, not the subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a redirect tag `[R]` into folder2 `.htaccess` `RewriteRule`.

This way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.com/subdirectory1
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subdirectory1/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ subdirectory1/$1 [R] 

ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.com/subdirectory2
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subdirectory2/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ subdirectory2/$1 [R] 

ReWriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.com/subdirectory3
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subdirectory3/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ subdirectory3/$1 [R]
```

Comment: I think you need another redirection on root folder:
    `ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ folder2/$1 [R]`
Have a try

Comment: i did and unfortunately still the same

Comment: Test this: Keep the redirect in the root folder and then delete the  rewrite rules into the folder2 folder.