# htaccess: remove cgit.cgi from path

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, fastcgi, cgit

So I just installed cgit on a shared host. I custom compiled it and use symlinks from `$HOME/mydomain-and-public-www-folder.tld/g` to `$HOME/local/lib/cgit/prod` to link `$HOME/local/lib/cgit/${git describe}` to a build from my updated builds to test the latest version. What does this include?

```
[sharedhost]$ pwd
$HOME/local/lib/cgit/prod
[sharedhost]$ ls
.htaccess  cgit.cgi  cgit.css  cgit.png lib/
```

Now, that looks all nice and good on the landing page when I put in `https://mydomain.tld/g/` in the browser and I see the pretty cgit interface. When I click any link, I get the proper repos, but all the formatting is gone (the CSS, PNG, and JS files go bye-bye, and all the links are in the form `https://mydomain.tld/g/cgit.cgi/randomrepo.git` for all the URLs. Of course all the files in the prod path are not working, because the browser looks for things like `https://mydomain.tld/g/cgit.cgi/cgit.css` instead of the needed `https://mydomain.tld/g/cgit.css`. Now, this was my basic .htaccess file to get it working.

```
[sharedhost]$ more .htaccess 
# GIT BEGIN ###########################################################

Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI 

Action fastcgi-script cgit.cgi

SetEnv HTTP_CGIT_CONFIG /home/username/local/lib/cgit/cgit-conf/cgitrc

RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex cgit.cgi

# GIT END ############################################################

# AUTHENTICATION BEGIN ###############################################
AuthType Digest
AuthName "cgitdigestdomain"
AuthDigestDomain /cgitdigestdomain/
AuthUserFile  /home/username/local/lib/cgit/cgit-conf/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
# AUTHENTICATION END  ################################################
```

I have tried a whole bunch of Rewrite patterns recommended like this [1] or that [2]. I am relatively new to more advanced .htaccess rules, so can someone point on how to remove `cgit.cgi` from the URLs with mod-rewrite *and* ensure css and png files in the same directory are accessible *and* QSA/query strings are handled properly. Sorry for the long post. I thought more detail would show why the obvious how-tos on this were not working for me.

[1] [Remove 'index.php' from URL with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608366/remove-index-php-from-url-with-htaccess)

[2] [htaccess remove subdirectory from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172630/htaccess-remove-subdirectory-from-url)

**UPDATE**:

Both answers seem to be good, but I do not think I am understanding the virtual-root and scan-path features, but it seems like these answers go farther than before, but the critical part is still missing. Any url to a repo (which is in a far removed path `$HOME/data/scm/priv`) is not getting redirected properly, and I get a 404.

```
[Fri Jul 13 01:16:18 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: $HOME/mydomain-and-public-www-folder.tld/missing.html, referer: https://domain.tld/g/
[Fri Jul 13 01:24:20 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: $HOME/mydomain-and-public-www-folder.tld/failed_auth.html, referer: https://domain.tld/g/
[Fri Jul 13 01:24:21 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: $HOME/mydomain-and-public-www-folder.tld/g/bicon.git, referer: https://domain.tld/g/
[Fri Jul 13 01:24:21 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: $HOME/mydomain-and-public-www-folder.tld/missing.html, referer: https://domain.tld/g/
[Fri Jul 13 01:26:11 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: $HOME/mydomain-and-public-www-folder.tld/g/admin-scripts.git, referer: https://domain.tld/g/
[Fri Jul 13 01:26:11 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: $HOME/mydomain-and-public-www-folder.tld/missing.html, referer: https://domain.tld/g/
```

Names/IPs changed to protect the innocent, but you get the point. So it appears the repo requests are not going back to the cgit CGI, so where are they going? I working on trying to get better redirect logs. We shall see.

**UPDATE 2:**

And of course, `RewriteLog` is a directive you cannot put in `.htaccess` as I forgot, silly me. Not sure what to do now on a shared hosting. How obnoxious. This is one of several issues that pushed me to look into VPS hosting and bite the money bullet and use this shared host for only really stupid stuff.

**P.S.:** I did email the original issue as is to the cgit dev list, and never got a response on this either. So they do not care and feel it is a moronic question, not sure. Haha.

Answer (score 4):

Usually this kind of problem is much easier to solve if you have some help from your tool. And you do.

According to [this page](http://hjemli.net/git/cgit/tree/cgitrc?id=bb3e7950c39b67e863a618b3a0e766544b65d3cb#n10) You can set the `virtual-root` setting (in your case to "/g" and use these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^/g/$ /g/cgit.cgi                            [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/g/([^/]+)/$ /g/cgit.cgi?r=$1               [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/g/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /g/cgit.cgi?r=$1&p=$2  [L,QSA]
```

I adjusted the paths to what I think would be right for you but I'm not sure about the recursiveness here. It should work (becasue of the L) but if it does not, I suggest you rename the folder /g into something like /git and use it in the paths (e.g. /git/cgit.cgi)

As for the css and js files, you will need another rule, something like this:

```
ReWriteCond /g/$1 -f
ReWriteRule ^/g/(.+)$ - [L]
```

This should leave the url untouched if the file exists. Put this rule before the rules above.

---

**Update:**

I was hoping adding `virtual-root` would change the links on the page to the desired form; I suggest you double check that cgit.cgi has picked up the configuration.

However, if you would want to work around that, try this rule:

```
ReWriteCond /g/$1 -f
ReWriteRule ^/g/cgit.cgi/(.+)$ /g/$1 [L]
```

Comment: +1 If my reading of the question is correct, the second part of this answer is the important bit...

Comment: Yeah thanks, tried yours, and the final part, regardless of both rules, does not redirect to the script to get the repo, or so it appears. See above.

Comment: So if I manually change the rewrite rules `RewriteRule ^/g/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /g/cgit.cgi?r=$1&p=$2  [L,QSA]` manually, I get the desired result of course. I cannot figure out why these request URLs do not get rewritten and passed back, but it seems like you have the idea.

Comment: And yes, `virtual-root=/g` is set.

Comment: And I changed the rule to this (because I did remove `.git` from the repo URLS yet, cannot even get this working).

RewriteRule ^/g/$ /g/cgit.cgi                            [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/g/([^/]+).git/$ /g/cgit.cgi?r=$1               [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/g/([^/]+).git/([^/]+)/$ /g/cgit.cgi?r=$1&p=$2  [L,QSA]

Still no dice, I give up for another few hours.

Answer (score 1):

Fozi's answer didn't quite work in my case. These rewrite rules work well with `virtual-path=/` in the `/etc/cgitrc`.

```
<Directory /var/www/cgit>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (.*) /cgit.cgi/$1
</Directory>
```

Make sure to `restart` your web server instead of `reload`ing it when messing with cgit, because it seems to cache some things.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
# Redirect the browser to remove the "cgit.cgi" from the URL's address bar
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /g/cgit\.cgi/
RewriteRule ^g/cgit\.cgi/(.+)\.git /g/$1.git [R=301,L]

# Internally add the "cgit.cgi" so that it gets served properly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/g/cgit.cgi/
RewriteRule ^g/(.+)\.git /g/cgit.cgi/$1.git [L]
```

You'd want to probably insert that somewhere after the `RewriteEngine On`. The first rule checks if the requested URI contains `/g/cgit.cgi/` and ends with a `.git`, and if so, redirect with the `cgit.cgi` removed. This will make it so relative links to see will have a base of `/g/` instead of `/g/cgit.cgi/`. Then, we need to change them back internally, which is where the second rule comes in. If the request doesn't include a `cgit.cgi`, then internally add one in as long as the URI ends with `.git`.

---

EDIT: I may have misunderstood what you meant by "how to remove `cgit.cgi` from the URLs with mod-rewrite"

See if these rules work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/g/cgit\.cgi/(.+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/g/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^g/cgit\.cgi/(.+)$ /g/$1 [L]
```

The first condition checks if the request URI starts with `/g/cgit.cgi/` and makes a backreference to whatever is after it. Then it checks if there is physically a file that exists if the `cgit.cgi` part is removed, and if so, rewrite the URI so that it's removed.

This way, requests for your css and js and images that sit in the `/g/` directory, but get relative linked to from URL's like `/g/cgit.cgi/something.git` will internally resolve as long as the referenced resource is actually in `/g/`.

Comment: Didn't work. I still have the same problem. Also, you can remove file extensions (`.git`) from the git repo if cgit is properly configured. I would like that in theory, if this ever gets running. Nonetheless, your's did not work. I was hopeful though.

Comment: @alharaka may have misread your question, try the rules in the edit portion of answer

Comment: Like the other reply, I had issues. See above.